# \bigcup with a subscripted argument spreads over several lines

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, positioning, math-operators

I am trying to position some of the limit of this union on a line below it, because it occupies too much space on one line:

```
\bigcup_{\langle b, r'' \rangle \in 
\{\langle \eta_{sp} \eta_s  (a(\delta s)s), \; r\widehat{}(a(\delta' s)s) 
\rangle \mid man (a (\delta s) s) (\delta s) s \}} \{bla bla \}
```

How can I split up the subscript argument of `\bigcup` in `_{}`, so that it occupies several lines below? This is to avoid the inelegant presentation of a formula (see the picture below):

[image]

Comment: The package `amsmath` provide the `\substack` macro for this precise purpose, but I do not dare writing an answer because I wouldn't know how to split that thing meaningfully...

Comment: You could put the subscript into a \parbox given the width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would combine the `\substack{...}` macro of the `amsmath` package and the `\smashoperator[r]{...}` macro of the `mathtools` package. The `\substack` macro permits introducing line breaks in the argument of "large" operators (such as `\bigcup`). The `\smashoperator[r]` macro permits joining up the operator to the material to its right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\smashoperator' macro

\begin{document}
\[
\smashoperator[r]{\bigcup_{
\substack{\langle b, r'' \rangle\in\{\langle\eta_{sp}\eta_s(a(\delta s)s), \\
r(a(\delta' s)s)  \rangle \mid \text{man} (a (\delta s) s) (\delta s) s \}}} }
\, \{bla bla\ bla bla\ bla bla\ bla bla \}
\]
\end{document}
```